# Return output from destination column when sourced from three source columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I have a source table and a destination table, my source table has three columns that make up my destination target column. My destination column is Telephone and my source columns are WorkNumber, CellNumber,HomeNumber. When I look up a customer account I want to see the customerNumber in the destination column. So basically everything that is in my three source columns should be in my one destination column with its respective customer account. Is there a way in which I can set my destination column equal to my three source columns either through t-sql or ssis?

Comment: Please provide sample data, expected results and attempt. Words can be very confusing.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @CustomerId INT 

DECLARE cur_insert_phone CURSOR FOR 
SELECT CustomerId FROM SourceDatabase.Schema.SourceTable 
ORDER BY CustomerId

OPEN cur_insert_phone

FETCH NEXT FROM cur_insert_phone INTO @CustomerId

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 

BEGIN
    INSERT INTO DestinationDatabase.Schema.SourceTable (CustomerId, CustomerNumber, PhoneType)

    SELECT t.CustomerId, t.PhoneNumber, t.PhoneType
    FROM
    (SELECT CustomerId, WorkNumber,CellNumber,HomeNumber FROM SourceDatabase.Schema.SourceTable WHERE CustomerId = @CustomerId) p
    UNPIVOT 
        (
            PhoneNumber FOR PhoneType IN (WorkNumber,CellNumber,HomeNumber)
        ) AS t 

    FETCH NEXT FROM cur_insert_phone INTO @CustomerId

END

CLOSE cur_insert_phone
DEALLOCATE cur_insert_phone
GO
```